# Don't (verb) - (like) or (unlike) I did

Tags: grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context, verbs

Say my intention is to say
"I did this bad things to her, but you shouldn't do it".

-Don't do that mean thing to her like how I did.
-Don't do that mean thing to her like unlike how I did.

This is so confusing....
Please help!

Comment: I just answered this question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182428/dont-verb-like-or-unlike-i-did).

Answer (score 1):

Those two sentences are not correct. Consider the following ways to express the idea:

> Don't do the same mean thing I did to her.
>
> Don't hurt her like I did / the way I did.
>
> Don't repeat my mistakes.